# twitter выдает ошибку

Tags: android, twitter-api

twitter выдает ошибку. проблема заключается в том что в одном устройстве авторизуется без проблем. на другом выдает ошибку, как решить данную проблему?

401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
    
    
    Timestamp out of bounds
    /oauth/access_token

Comment: А что со временем и временной зоной на этих 2 девайсах?

Comment: решил проблему, надо было поставить московское время. +3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему, надо было поставить московское время. +3